# Angular Material: How do I disable right click on cdk overlay container?

Tags: angular, angular-material, fabricjs

I am using a mat-menu as contextmenu on a canvas object, the problem is when I right click the canvas object, the default browser contextmenu showed up, which it overlaped the actual contextmenu; I want to prevent the default contextmenu showing on the cdk-overlay-container element. The right click event is triggered from the child component(canvas) and I have called the preventDefault(), and the mat-menu is in the parent component.

Comment: if  it is parent div of canvas then. 
var div = document.getElementById('canvas-parent');
div.addEventListener("contextmenu", ( e )=> { e.preventDefault(); return false; } );

this should help.  also if not working with child  elements then  event bubble or propogations need to stop.

Comment: @khajaamin Thanks for the help. I have register the listener(preventDefault) in the parent component which contains the canvas component, but the div(cdk-overlay-container) is not belong to the parent component, it is generated by mat-menu, so I don't have the control of it. NVM, I think I could register the listener to the cdk-overlay-container element to prevent default contextmenu

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle?  I will try to help you

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me

```
@ViewChild("contextMenu") contextMenu: MatMenu;
...
document.getElementsByClassName(this.contextMenu.backdropClass).item(0)
                .addEventListener("contextmenu", event => {event.preventDefault()});
```